# Splitting char array adds (seemingly) random characters

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm pretty sure this is a rookie mistake, but I can't figure it out. I tried making a palindrome checker, but whenever I try to split a passed char array in half it adds random (?) characters at the end of the split char arrays. I tried googling but to no avail. Perhaps it has something to do with a null terminated string, but the length of the char array indicates that there are no other characters other than the ones I passed. Code here:

```
#include <iostream>

bool isPalindrome(char* passedString){
  int len = strlen(passedString);
  char lh[len/2];
  char rh[len/2];

  std::cout << "Length is: " << len << std::endl;

  if(len % 2 == 0){
    for(int i = 0; i < len/2; i++){
      lh[i] = passedString[i];
    }

    int tmpCount = 0;
    for(int i = len/2; i < len; i++){
      rh[tmpCount] = passedString[i];
      tmpCount++;
      }
   }

  std::cout << "Left half: " << lh << std::endl << "Right half: " << rh << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

int main(){
  isPalindrome("test");
  return 0;
}
```

Returns this output after compiling and executing:

```
Length is: 4
Left half: te�Y�
Right half: st�Y�
```

Comment: `char lh[len/2]`: runtime sized arrays is C99 feature not C++. Use a `std::string` instead to avoid such problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the two arrays of size `len/2+1` and add `\0` at the last position of each array.
For more insight as to how strings work with arrays and pointers, you can check this link: http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/string/intro/

Answer (score 2):

First of all string literals have types of constant character arrays. So if you want to call the function passing to it a string literal it has to be declared like

```
bool isPalindrome( const char *passedString );
```

Secondly there is no variable length arrays in C++ (though some compilers can support them). So these declarations

```
char lh[len/2];
char rh[len/2];
```

are not valid C++ declarations.

The both character arrays do not contain zero terminated strings. So this statement

```
std::cout << "Left half: " << lh << std::endl << "Right half: " << rh << std::endl;
```

can output some garbage.

Instead of `std::cout << lh` or `std::cout << rh` use

```
std::cout.write( lh, len / 2 );
```

and

```
std::cout.write( rh, len / 2 );
```

For example

```
std::cout << "Left half: ";
std::cout.write( lh, len / 2 ); 
std::cout << std::endl << "Right half: ";
std::cout.write( rh, len / 2 ) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I zero terminated both char arrays and it works fine now. My compiler (g++) did give a warning about the string literal conversion, but nothing about the runtime sized arrays... interesting.

Comment: @user1910584 This compiler has such own extension. The warning depends on the compiler options.